# Sublime Text 2 varying macro per syntax

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3

Lets say I have a shortcut that fires a macro to add curly braces after a function. But my curly braces are different for php than for javascript:

php:

```
function()
{
.....
}
```

javascript:

```
function(){
.....
}
```

Is there a way to have the same key binding for a macro that behaves different depending on the syntax I am writing in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can bind multiple commands (or macros in this case) to the same key and differentiate them with context entries.

You will probably want to define the context as

```
{ "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "source.js", "match_all": true }
```

and

```
{ "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "source.php", "match_all": true }
```

Comment: Although I rated the answer as accepted because it is the right answer. Somehow this does not work for me on osx. This thread http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/21146-key-binding-context-to-only-react-on-eg-python-code/ (2 years old) mentions the same bug as I experience. There is a solution in it which mentions using the operand not_equal.

Comment: For my case I solved by using `source.js` but not `source.javascript`. You may check this [post](http://kleineblase.wordpress.com/2013/05/26/syntax-specific-key-binding-in-sublime-text-2-e-g-fix-javascript-reindent-with-jsformat-and-ctrlshiftf/) for more

Comment: @vincentlcy thanks I'll update it. I don't know all the scopes off the top of my head, guess I was wrong about that one :)