# How to set same key-bindings for different syntax? Sublime Text 2

Tags: ide, format, sublimetext2

How do I set same key-bindings for different syntax in Sublime Text 2? For example, I have three different formatting packages for HTML/CSS, Javascript, and Python. I would like them to have the same key-binding (ctrl + shift + f). This way when I switch between syntaxes, I can use the same hotkey to format my code.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create the key bindings with a context for selector. See my answer at [Sublime Text 2 varying macro per syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16520165/sublime-text-2-varying-macro-per-syntax) for more information on that.